# How to load a ontolgy in a quick way using jena?

Tags: java, file, time, jena, ontology

I´m trying to load some ontologies for a project. Right now i´m using ontologies from bioportal, some of them are really heavy, 200 mb or 400 mb, and it take allot of time for java to load them.

I dont know if i´m loading the files in the right way or there is any work around to make the loading time smaller.

this is a part of my code, where i load the ontologies:

```
System.out.println("loading the model...");
    model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_LITE_MEM);
    listPaths = new LinkedList();
    //sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try{

        if(args[0].equals("0")){

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("ontologies/camera.owl");
            model.read(in, null);
            NS = NS0;
            in.close();

        }else if(args[0].equals("1")){

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("ontologies/NCITNCBO.owl");
            model.read(in, null);
            NS = NS1;
            //in.close();

        }else if(args[0].equals("2")){

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("ontologies/HL7.ttl");
            model.read(in,null, "TTL");
            NS = "http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/HL7/";
            in.close();

        }else if(args[0].equals("3")){

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("ontologies/LOINC.ttl");
            model.read(in,null, "TTL");
            NS = "http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/LNC/";
            in.close();

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Ontology loaded!");

    //some info about the ontology
    int maxChildcount = 0;
    int numClasses = 0;
    int numChilds = 0;
    int numChildsClass = 0;
    Iterator i = model.listClasses();

    while( i.hasNext() ){
        numClasses++;
        OntClass c = (OntClass) i.next();

        //get num childs
        if(c.hasSubClass()){
            Iterator i2 = c.listSubClasses();
                    while(i2.hasNext()){
                        i2.next();
                        numChilds++;
                        numChildsClass++;

                    }

            if(numChildsClass > maxChildcount)
                maxChildcount = numChildsClass;
        }

        numChildsClass = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("NumChilds: " + numChilds + " MaxChildCLass: " + maxChildcount + " numClasses: " + numClasses);
    System.out.println("Paths for class: " + NS +  args[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BufferedInputStream` around the `FileInputStream` to ensure that the content is buffered appropriately. Also, don't comment out the `in.close()` in the second call.